# Padding inside checkbox flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Want to more space between checkmark and checkbox

code

```
 Transform.scale(
                  scale: 1.3,
                  child: Checkbox(
                    checkColor: AppColors.buttonColor,
                  activeColor: AppColors.textWhiteColor,
                      side: MaterialStateBorderSide.resolveWith(
                        (states) => BorderSide(
                            width: 1.0, color: AppColors.unSelectedColor),
                      ),
                      materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                      value: isCheck,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          isCheck = value!;
                        });
                      }),
                ),
```

when checkbox active border color blue and padding between checkmark and checkbox border

like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check below source for custom checkbox. This will fulfill your requirement.

Source:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class CustomCheckBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool value;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;
  final Color checkedIconColor;
  final Color checkedFillColor;
  final IconData checkedIcon;
  final Color uncheckedIconColor;
  final Color uncheckedFillColor;
  final IconData uncheckedIcon;
  final double? borderWidth;
  final double? checkBoxSize;
  final bool shouldShowBorder;
  final Color? borderColor;
  final double? borderRadius;
  final double? splashRadius;
  final Color? splashColor;
  final String? tooltip;
  final MouseCursor? mouseCursors;

  const CustomCheckBox({
    Key? key,
    required this.value,
    required this.onChanged,
    this.checkedIconColor = Colors.white,
    this.checkedFillColor = Colors.teal,
    this.checkedIcon = Icons.check,
    this.uncheckedIconColor = Colors.white,
    this.uncheckedFillColor = Colors.white,
    this.uncheckedIcon = Icons.close,
    this.borderWidth,
    this.checkBoxSize,
    this.shouldShowBorder = false,
    this.borderColor,
    this.borderRadius,
    this.splashRadius,
    this.splashColor,
    this.tooltip,
    this.mouseCursors,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomCheckBoxState createState() => _CustomCheckBoxState();
}

class _CustomCheckBoxState extends State<CustomCheckBox> {
  late bool _checked;
  late CheckStatus _status;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _init();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(CustomCheckBox oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    _init();
  }

  void _init() {
    _checked = widget.value;
    if (_checked) {
      _status = CheckStatus.checked;
    } else {
      _status = CheckStatus.unchecked;
    }
  }

  Widget _buildIcon() {
    late Color fillColor;
    late Color iconColor;
    late IconData iconData;

    switch (_status) {
      case CheckStatus.checked:
        fillColor = widget.checkedFillColor;
        iconColor = widget.checkedIconColor;
        iconData = widget.checkedIcon;
        break;
      case CheckStatus.unchecked:
        fillColor = widget.uncheckedFillColor;
        iconColor = widget.uncheckedIconColor;
        iconData = widget.uncheckedIcon;
        break;
    }

    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: fillColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(widget.borderRadius ?? 6)),
        border: Border.all(
          color: widget.shouldShowBorder ? (widget.borderColor ?? Colors.teal.withOpacity(0.6)) : (!widget.value ? (widget.borderColor ?? Colors.teal.withOpacity(0.6)) : Colors.transparent),
          width: widget.shouldShowBorder ? widget.borderWidth ?? 2.0 : 1.0,
        ),
      ),
      child: Icon(
        iconData,
        color: iconColor,
        size: widget.checkBoxSize ?? 18,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: _buildIcon(),
      onPressed: () => widget.onChanged(!_checked),
      splashRadius: widget.splashRadius,
      splashColor: widget.splashColor,
      tooltip: widget.tooltip,
      mouseCursor: widget.mouseCursors ?? SystemMouseCursors.click,
    );
  }
}

enum CheckStatus {
  checked,
  unchecked,
}
```

Link:
https://github.com/DipakShrestha-ADS/custom_check_box/blob/master/lib/custom_check_box.dart

Comment: the asker asked for padding inside checkbox not custom checkbox

Comment: That options is not available. you have to create custom checkbox to do the same.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question :/

Comment: If you can find padding inside checkbox then please send me. I have shared the way to achieve the task. If you don't feel it is useful don't use it. But you can't put your comment on someone effort. If you have way share it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "Padding" by increasing the value of `strokeAlign` property on `Checkbox.side`:

```
Checkbox(
      visualDensity: VisualDensity.comfortable,
      checkColor: checked
          ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface
          : Colors.transparent,
      side: MaterialStateBorderSide.resolveWith(
        (states) => BorderSide(
          color: checked
              ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary
              : Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
          strokeAlign: 5,
          width: .8,
        ),
      ),
      fillColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) {
        return Colors.transparent;
      }),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      ),
      value: checked,
      onChanged: onChanged,
    )[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image: Padded checkbox shown as checked and unchecked]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no official way to add content padding or reduce the size of the checkmark inside the checkbox.

What you can do though, is setting the stroke color to the color of your checkbox background, and then increasing the stroke width, and finally reducing the size of the checkbox entirely using transform.

```
Transform.scale(
  scale: 0.8,
  child: Checkbox(
    activeColor: theme,
    splashRadius: 0.0,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
    ),
    side: MaterialStateBorderSide.resolveWith(
       (states) => BorderSide(
            width: 6.0,
            color: controller.borderClr.value,
            strokeAlign:
                BorderSide.strokeAlignCenter,
                   ),
    ),
    value: true,
  ),
)
```

or, create a custom checkbox widget as @ABV suggested.